# Print String Values After strpos() search

Tags: php

I'm still relatively new to PHP, but I'm trying to write a script that would print only the next 35 or so characters in a string, after it has found a certain word or two. I'm familiar with using `strpos()` to find the particular value, just unsure how to go about printing the next 35 characters after it has found the string value that I would set.

So if the random string entered contained the word, "something" from a sentence entered originally as, "My friend had found something in the park next to the bench." It would only print, " in the park next to the bench."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
substr($string, strpos($string, $searchedWord) + strlen($searchedWord), 35);
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of the word you're searching for is determined by `strpos()` as you've mentioned; next you need to skip over that word and return the next 35 characters:

```
$str = 'My friend had found something in the park next to the bench.';
$needle = 'something';

substr($str, strpos($str, $needle) + strlen($needle), 35);
```

If there's a possibility that `$needle` is not found in the string (in which case `strpos()` returns `false`), you need to add a condition:

```
if (($pos = strpos($str, $needle)) !== false) {
    return substr($str, $pos + strlen($needle), 35);
} else {
    return ''; // search failed, return what you like
}
```

*This assumes running inside a function.*

See also: [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)

Answer (score -1):

What you need is [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$start = strpos('something', $string);
echo substr($string, $start, 35);
```